# Как выровнять букву (или слово) внутри canvas по центру, вне зависимости от ширины и высоты?

Tags: javascript

Как реализовать букву (или слово) внутри квадрата всегда по центру?

При этом не важна какая ширина или высота квадрата.

Нужно как то вот эти значения `12, 90` заменить на динамические

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById('chart').getContext('2d');
ctx.canvas.width = 100;
ctx.canvas.height = 100;
ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
ctx.font = "120px 'Segoe UI', sans-serif";
ctx.save();
ctx.fillText("A", 12, 90);
ctx.restore();
```

```css
#chart {
  border: 10px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="chart"></canvas>
```

Comment: `ctx.textAlign = ‘center’`

Comment: Добавление к вопросу, еще хотелось бы понять как сделать чтобы при наведении на canvas текст менялся бы на другой цвет

Comment: @Stranger in the Q, а по вертикале?